# Javascript XSLT with Chrome not creating dropdownlist option elements

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt, html-select

My problem is that I can't create a dynamic dropdownlist for Chrome. It is working without problems in IE and Firefox. 
I'm using javascript on my website for XSLT, with an webworker loading the XML and XSL files via XMLHttpRequest. The XSLT is done with the XSLTProcessor for Firefox and Chrome and for IE with XMLDOM. This is working without Problems on different pages, I get my checkboxes and input fields like expected, for IE, Firefox and Chrome.
But on one site I have to show a dropdownlist with values from another XML file and I have to select one value. Chrome is making the XSLT transformation and is returning the document without errors, but between the `<select>`-tags there are no `<option>` tags.

This is my reduced XML configuration file, only containing the value I need here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Device>
  <Standardsprache Sprache="Deutsch" Datei="lang_german.xml" />
</Device>
```

My reduced XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="Sprachauswahl">English</xsl:param>
...
<xsl:template match="Standardsprache">
  ...
  <select id="Sprachen" name="Sprachen" size="6" onclick="language_js(document.Allgemein_form.Sprachen.selectedIndex)">
    <xsl:variable name="Sprachenliste" select="document('/data/html/sprachenliste.xml')" /> <!-- OK IE, FF -->
    <!--xsl:variable name="Sprachenliste" select="document('http://IPAddress/data/html/sprachenliste.xml')" /--> <!-- OK IE, FF -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$Sprachenliste/Sprachenliste/Sprache/name">
      <xsl:variable name="name" select="."/>
      <option>
        <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="$Sprachauswahl = $name">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
      </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </select>
```

And the language XML file (`sprachenliste.xml`) with the values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sprachenliste>
    <Sprache><name>Deutsch</name></Sprache>
    <Sprache><name>English</name></Sprache>
    <Sprache><name>Espanol</name></Sprache>
</Sprachenliste>
```

After transformation I get a document in IE and Firefox containing the dropdownlist with values:

```
<select id="Sprachen" name="Sprachen" size="6" onclick="language_js(document.Allgemein_form.Sprachen.selectedIndex)">
  <option value="Deutsch">Deutsch</option>
  <option value="English" selected="selected">English</option>
  <option value="Espanol">Espanol</option>
</select>
```

Chrome is also returning the complete document but between the `<select>` tags the `<option>` tags are missing. And there are no errors in the Chrome developer tool.

I can open the language XSL file directly with Chrome over HTTP

> http://IPAddress/data/html/sprachenliste.xml

I also searched around, and there seems to be a Problem to load files with Chrome when they are local, so I also set these start parameters to chrome without success:

> --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security flags

But this was just a try, because I run the site on a webserver on a Windows CE6 device. Also I don´t want to set Chrome start parameters to get my site displayed.

Either there is a problem with Chrome loading the file or Chrome is not able to make the for-each loop on the values of the file.

Is there another way to load XML files inside XSL files for Chrome?

Or is there a way to set the language values directly inside the XSL file without loading an extra XML file?

Comment: Well, you have thrown in a lot of complications that we can't test.Does that XSLT code work with Chrome when you load it directly referenced in the `xml-stylesheet` pi of an XML document? Does it work with Javascript without using web workers? Have you tried to debug e.g. `count($Sprachenliste//*)`?

Comment: So https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API says " workers may use XMLHttpRequest for network I/O, with the exception that the responseXML and channel attributes on XMLHttpRequest always return null.". That way I suppose you pass on the responseText from the worker to the main code and then use DOMParser, is that true? That might explain why the `document` function in XSLT has no base URI to resolve that relative URI you pass in.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718434 suggests this is a known issue in general with using the `document` function in XSLT in Chrome.